# Using a watcher decorator in a Vuex store with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-module-decorators

I have a getter on a Vuex store called storeOne (not namespaced) :

```
public get IsHistoricMode(): boolean {
    return this.historicMode;
}
```

I have another store called storeTwo (namespaced).
I tried to track state changes from "IsHistoricMode" getter with a watcher :

```
@Getter('IsHistoricMode')
private isHistoricMode!: boolean;

@Watch('isHistoricMode')
private historicModeChange() {
    console.log("historicMode changed !");
}
```

If I mutate the value HistoricMode in storeOne.
My watcher in storeTwo is never triggered.

It seems possible to use a watcher in Vuex : https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch.

The npm packages used are :

- Vue 2.6.14
- Vuex 3.6.2
- TypeScript 3.1.1
- vuex-module-decorators 0.9.11
- vuex-class 0.3.2

Could you help us please ?

Thank you

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and a way to reproduce the problem. The problem is already low-profile, you're using the libs that aren't officially supported and no longer maintained, it doesn't have good chance to be solved. What are Getter and Watch? They aren't in vuex-module-decorators

Comment: The getter is in vuex-class (0.3.2). It is provided with vuex. Is there a way to do it in vuex/typescript without decorator ?

Comment: This is what the question should have been said in the first place, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . That you mix them without this being explicitly suggested in Vuex decorator docs suggests that you're doing something that isn't expected to work correctly. The problem with these decorators is that they do some work that isn't documented and cannot be understood without digging into their source code, that they are niche libs that aren't actively maintained means that you're with your own problems once they occur, I'd advice against using them at this point at all.

Comment: The docs suggest that Vuex watcher is set with store.watch method, there's no way how Vue (not Vuex) Watch decorator could be aware of that, that's the main problem here, look no further. You can always fall back to the official way, `store.watch(...)`, and it's reasonably well typed to be used with TS